# Errors as i'm trying to install pandas-profiling in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I'm pretty new to data science, tried to install pandas-profiling in anaconda to use it in jupyter notebook in the conda prompt.
However, I won't work.
First I tried the pip install pandas-profiling, this gave me lots of errors;

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Adgang nægtet: 'C:\Users\jonas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-byfk9r7u\numpy\core\_multiarray_tests.cp39-win_amd64.pyd'
> Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

> WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -atplotlib (c:\users\jonas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)

Then I wrote 'conda install pandas-profiling' in the prompt and this came up;

[image]

However, it still doesn't work, when I'm opening up jupyter notebook and try writing "from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport"... i now get this error inside jupyter notebook:

ImportError: cannot import name 'ABCIndexClass' from 'pandas.core.dtypes.generic' (C:\Users\jonas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\generic.py)

Hope anyone can help me out here, it's so complicated for me rn
thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: ⚠️ pandas-profiling package naming was changed. To continue profiling data use ydata-profiling instead!

Comment: However, are you sure you want pandas-profiling and not Pandas?

Comment: Is there any downsides to using pandas profiling? I'd imagine to use both packages

Comment: Pandas normally is enough